mac mini m2 terminal has very strange behavior
I just recently got a new mac mini, and am finding the terminal to behave very oddly and I am not sure why...
For one thing, I have vim setup with solarize as the colors.

When I ssh into the mac mini, and open vim, it is NOT using solarize -- or at least it is unable to display the colors properly.  echo $TERM shows xterm-256color which is the same for my other mac which displays solarize properly (and they are both using the same .vimrc file)

I have vim keybindings in the terminal set -o vi ...  but when I up-arrow to a previus command, if I press 0 to go to the beginning of the line, then w to move a few words ahead, if I go into insert mode and then hit backspace, the cursor will not move back.  If I switch to bash, this seems to not happen, so I am thinking it's zsh?

Normally, when I have a bunch of text in my terminal window, I run vim, do what I need to do, and when I quit vim, I will see all of the original text output that was on the screen before I launched vim.  Now on this machine, when I quit out of vim, I just see the vim buffer with my terminal prompt at the bottom...


How can I fix these 3 issues?

For the solarize color scheme in vim, in addition to specifying which scheme to use in your .vimrc you also have to put the color scheme into $HOME/.vim/colors/. Can you confirm the file is there.

@Alex yes, I determined this is from running "screen" ...  Apparently the version of screen installed on mac os does not support 256 colors.. recompiling it solved it.

still am hoping for help with 2 and 3, but 3 also seems screen related.  2 happens outside of screen too.
